# Using sum() function of mySQL query with left outer join

Tags: mysql

I have three tables named as Table1, Table2, Table3. Table1 has three coloumns. They are studentId, studentName, taskName. Table2 has two coloumns as Id and student name. Table2 includes name of students who are not taking a certain module. Table3 contains two coloumns assigning each tasks to a supervisor. More than one task can be assigned under a supervisor. Here I am using following query to count the number of tasks per supervisor:

```
SELECT Table3.supervisor, COUNT(*) as Total FROM issues LEFT OUTER JOIN
Table2 ON Table1.studentName=Table2.studentName LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON
Table1.taskName=Table3.taskName WHERE Table2.userId is null GROUP BY Table3.supervior
```

Can anyone help to write a query to find total number of tasks allocated for students who take certain module?

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out it.
Answer is :

```
SELECT SUM(Total) FROM (
SELECT Table3.supervisor, COUNT(*) as Total FROM issues LEFT OUTER JOIN
Table2 ON Table1.studentName=Table2.studentName LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON
Table1.taskName=Table3.taskName WHERE Table2.userId is null GROUP BY Table3.supervior) as summation
```

Comment: You might as well just remove `GROUP BY Table3.supervior` (and `Table3.supervisor` in the `select`). Side question: Who designed `table2`? If it was your teacher, I hope he has a reason; also, it might be some view. But if you designed it that way, you should rethink it: it does not make sense to store the information that a student will participate in a module by *not* having an entry in `table2`. Just imagine the effort you need to make if you want to add a fresh student to the university (without any modules). You would need to add him in table2 (and similar tables for other modules).